# Making Cells Consecutive when Cell Contains Letters and Numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a very basic understanding of excel formulas and am trying to figure out how to make a column containing a value of both letters and numbers run consecutively by changing a single field. I cannot separate the text and numbers into separate columns. For example. I have a column titled "epic link" and in that column I have 26 rows. I am hoping to only have to update the 26th row and have it auto update the other 25. So they go NXZ-13164 and I want the one above it to be NXZ-13163 and so on. They all need to have the NXZ- and then the next number should go down by 1. Hopefully that makes sense. I've been able to get the numbers to subtract but can't figure out how to make the NXZ- stay in there too. Is this possible?

Clarification with pic below: Right now I am dragging cell D2 all the way down to consecutively "number" the items and then I have to go copy/past to make it look like the picture because certain rows need the same number. I know how to make that happen automatically but what I'd like to do is type in D26 and have D25 be one less as shown in the picture. If I can get that formula I can do the rest. Does that help?

[image: Example of my Sheet]

Comment: You can use a custom format for this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks I added an image and tried to explain it a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Select cells
Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>1</kbd>,
select `User defined` or `Custom` (LibreOffice or Excel)
Type `"NZX-"0`in the format field,
click OK

Type any formula resulting in a positive number in the cells you had selected above and the result will be **displayed** with `NZX-` prepended to the number.

*More?

https://help.libreoffice.org/7.5/ug/search?P=formatting+numbers

https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/ug/text/scalc/guide/format_value_userdef.html

...*

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Wlecome to SuperUser, thank you's are provided by clicking either on - the tick (making it green) or the up or down arrows - to the left of this text, :-) have a nice day.